# How to append `text` element by conditional in d3js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I would like to append the `text` node by conditional on my graphics. i am trying this, but not working.

what is the correct way to do that?

```
that.texts = that.groupElement.selectAll(label+"text").data(that.data).enter();
```

the approach is not working is here :

```
this.texts.append(function(d, i) {
            if(i== 0 && that.elementId === "paymentGraph")  {
                return "text" //so only one let created!
            }})
            .attr({
                class : this.elementId + "title"
            })
            .text("Total Contract Amount")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

The approach working is here : ( but I have 2 `text` node, 1 is empty)

```
this.texts.append("text") //adding 2 text element.
           .attr({
              class : this.elementId + "title"
          })
          .text(function(d,i) {
              if(i==0 && that.elementId === "paymentGraph") 
                 return "Total Contract Amount"; //only one required
          })
          .style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Any one help me to showing correct way to append the node by conditional please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `this.texts`?

Comment: ok, let me update that too..

Comment: @Munick - please see the update.

Comment: is `that.data` an array of length 2?

Comment: yes, it has only 2 values

Answer (score 2):

`append` isn't where you want to make the condition.... 
`append` takes a node type and your function doesn't return anything half the time.

You should be using the selector to filter out what elements you want to append to and data for how many you want to append.

I think for you that would look something like

```
that.texts = that.groupElement.select("#paymentGraph")
             .selectAll(label+"text").data([that.data[0]]).enter();
this.texts.append("text")
.attr({class : this.elementId + "title"})
.text("Total Contract Amount")
.style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

or possibly

```
if(that.elementId === "paymentGraph") {    
    that.texts = that.groupElement.selectAll(label+"text").data([that.data[0]]).enter();
    this.texts.append("text")
    .attr({class : this.elementId + "title"})
    .text("Total Contract Amount")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");
}
```

Comment: can i use the function instead of using 'that.data[0]` ?

Comment: I am using same method for multiple graphs, the solution one you given is hard coded, but here I am doing with dynamic.

Comment: a function in `data` acts as the [key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data), so a function in there won't do the trick. Why can't you filter the data array before hand?

Comment: so, do you asking to set the array (required) from values and store in variable?

Comment: yeah, something like [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)